# AppDelegate instance variable getting zombie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In the AppDelegate I have a user variable in order to be accessible throughout the application. Tha AppDelegate code is the following:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, ...> {

@private User *_appUser;
...
}

- (void)setUser:(User *)value;
- (User *)appUser;

- (void)setUser:(User *)value
{
   @synchronized(self)
   {
    if(_appUser != value)
    {
        [_appUser release];
        _appUser = [value retain];
        [NSUserDefaultsManager SaveUser:_appUser];
    }
}
```

}

```
- (User *)appUser
{
   if(_appUser == nil)
    return [NSUserDefaultsManager GetUser];
else
    return _appUser;
}
```

The first time, when the user registers, I set the user via a ViewController by doing

```
[((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) setUser:user];
```

The thing is that when I need to get the user by doing

```
User *user = [((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) appUser];
```

in the appUser method of the AppDelegate, the _appUser ivar is Zombie.
Any workaround for that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your getter method the culprit?  You are returning the _appUser without the usual retain/autorelease pattern.  Can you resolve the problem by making your getter method:

```
- (User *)appUser
{
   if(_appUser == nil)
    return [NSUserDefaultsManager GetUser];
else
    return [[_appUser retain] autorelease];
}
```

or...

```
- (User *)appUser
{
    if(_appUser == nil)
      _appUser = [[NSUserDefaultsManager GetUser] retain];
    return [[_appUser retain] autorelease];
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help either. _appUser is still zombie in this method. I added, also, _appUser = [[[User alloc] init] retain] in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but to no avail.

Comment: Are you directly accessing the _appUser ivar anywhere else in the application delegate rather than through the accessors?  Also, I'm not sure what kind of object (and with what retain count), the [NSUserDefaultsManager GetUser] method is returning...

Comment: The GetUser method makes use of NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData so I suppose returns an autoreleased object. Also, in the setter method 'value' is an autoreleased object.